# Django DRF - Sending email with html template - html template appears as plain text

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to send emails from django using a html template. It does send the email but the html is sent as plain text. How can I make the email appear as html to the receiver?

I'm using Django 4.0

views.py

```
# import file with html content
html_version = 'activate_email.html'
html_message = render_to_string(html_version, {'context': context })

email = EmailMessage(
    'Website email verification',  
    html_message,
    'info@example.co',  
    [user.email],  
)
email.send()
```

activate_email.html

```
{% autoescape off %}
<h1>Test</h1>
{% endautoescape %}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the `content_subtype` attribute on the [EmailMessage](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/email/#the-emailmessage-class) class to change the main content.

```
email = EmailMessage(
    'Website email verification',  
    html_message,
    'info@example.co',  
    [user.email],  
)
email.content_subtype = "html"  # Main content is now text/html
email.send()
```